# (awk) Discard records with truncated string in a field

Tags: arrays, awk

I would need to discard all the lines with truncated strings in $2 (using awk). A truncated string being a string incorporated into a longer one (e.g. records 2 and 4 below are truncated compared to record 1).

input (tab separated):

```
line1 AAABBAAA
line2 BB
line3 CCCC
line4 B
```

To get this output:

```
line1 AAABBAAA
line3 CCCC
```

I tried something like:

```
{array[++a]=$2}

END{
  for(i in array){
    if($2 ~ /i/ && (length($2) >= length(i))){
      print $0
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this by using the [index function](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html)

```
awk '{for (k in a) if (index(a[k], $2) > 0) next;a[$2]=$2};{print}' file.txt
line1 AAABBAAA
line3 CCCC
```